# Get mutual connections MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a followers table

```
followers: id, follower_id, subject_id,...
```

I want to get mutual followers 'connections' where the subject follows the followers

I tried a `JOIN`

```
SELECT t1.`subject_id`, t2.`follower_id`
FROM
`followers` t1
JOIN
`followers` t2
ON
t1.`follower_id` = t2.`subject_id`
WHERE
t1.`follower_id` = 12
OR
t2.`subject_id` = 12
GROUP BY 
t1.`id`,
t2.`id`
```

But im getting inconsistent results

I would like to get:

`connection_id` <- this user was followed and followed back

EDIT:

I was overthinking this.

I got the results I need using a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM `followers` WHERE
 `follower_id` = 12
 AND
 `subject_id` IN (SELECT `follower_id` FROM `followers` WHERE `subject_id` = 12)

 GROUP BY `subject_id`
```

I still want to know how to do it with a JOIN so I will leave the question open.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fol2.followerid, fol1.subjectid
FROM followers fol1
JOIN followers fol2 
     ON fol1.subjectid = fol2.subjectid 
     AND fol1.followerid <> fol2.followerid
WHERE fol1.followerid = 12
```

Because your only after similar persons, with similar likes you should remove the person's own id from the list to be joined. Otherwise it'll show "We noticed you like what you like" just seems a little silly.

It's pretty simple really, all your doing is joining on the same subject.

I'm not sure why your grouping, as it shouldn't return any repeat so it won't really do anything other than slow down the script.

I know it your personal choice, instead of having the following:

```
Followers: id, follower_id, subject_id
```

I'd have:

```
Followings: following_id, user_id, subject_id
```

It reads nicer and at least in my mind makes sense easier.